# Inserting arrays and React Components into HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Why in this code

```
var x = [4, 9, 16, 25];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

Does the inner HTML show the numbers without the square brackets? (AKA how come it does not insert the array?)

And in this code

```
class BusinessList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="BusinessList">
                {
                this.props.businesses.map(business => {
                    return <Business business={business} />
                })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have the same question + does the div look like this:

```
<div>
    <Business business={business} />, <Business business={business} />, etc.
</div>
```

Isn't it supposed to be (without commas and each on a separate line):

```
<div>
   <Business business={business} />
   <Business business={business} />
   <Business business={business} />
    etc.
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The first example simply coerces the array to a string, as the `innerHTML` property can only ever be a string. In the second the JSX is converted into calls to `React.CreateElement`, which handles arrays by simply putting the resulting HTML nodes as siblings in the (virtual) DOM.

Comment: First off, you ***really, really shouldn't*** use `innerHTML` for such purpose - `textContent` is faster and safer. Second, if you need to insert arrays or objects, preserving their JavaScript notations, you may want to use `JSON.stringify()` as your input will be translated to string anyways (which is, by the way, the answer to the *why* question - that's how JS casts array to string).

Comment: The answer to your second question - what react does under the hood is not straightforward `innerHTML` manipulation as in your first sample. React accepts array as valid JSX child and turns the array of JSX elements into proper HTML markup, so the equivalent of `.map()` output in your example would rather be: `<div><Business business={this.props.businesses[0]} /><Business business={this.props.businesses[1] />..`